# TeXnicCenter tex not adding problem

Tags: minipage

Hi i'm writing a resume with TeXnicCenter the code is loaded but in a page the text is not coming to a new a page eventhough it is loaded continously to privouse text?

Comment: Close the cventriers environment (or however it is called) where you need the page break and start a new one for the entries on the new page.